# How to add HH:MM:SS format to the LocalDate in java?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, localdate

```
LocalDate beginDate = LocalDate.now()
        .with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
        .atStartOfDay()
        .minusDays(8)
        .toLocalDate();
```

I am getting the previous week begin date using the above code line. However I want to add HH:MM:SS format to this. I have tried different ways to get this. Tried using LocalDateTime instead of Localdate. But could not find `atStartOfDay()` method for LocalDateTime. Help me to add HH:MM:SS to `beginDate` variable

Comment: How about not converting back to local date at the end?

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense, because time **atStartOfDay** is always 00:00:00.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen No, not in a zoned date-time. Some days on some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00:00.

Comment: But not from a "local" perspektive, isn't it?

Comment: Append to your expression: `.atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)`. Yields a `LocalDateTime`, that is with time of day. Only as Basil Bourque said, it will in some cases give you a time that isn’t valid for your time zone.

Comment: Are you trying to go back 8 days, or go back to previous Monday?

Comment: — or go back to the start of the previous week? Not everywhere in the world does the week begin on Monday.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate                                   // Represents a date only, without a time of day, without a time zone or offset. 
.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Amman" ) )           // Returns a `LocalDate`. 
.minusDays( 8 )                             // Returns another `LocalDate` object. 
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Amman" ) )  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime`. 
.toString()                                 // Returns a `String` object, with text in standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of time zone in brackets.
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/y3JnxS). Notice that on that date in that zone, the day began at 01:00, *not* 00:00.

> 2022-02-22T01:00+03:00[Asia/Amman]

## No “format” involved

Date-time objects do not have a “format”. Text has a format. Date-time objects are not text.

## `LocalDate` has no time of day

You said:

> add HH:MM:SS format to [a `LocalDate` object]

A `LocalDate` represents a date only, without a time of day, without a time zone or offset.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Apparently you want the first moment of the day eight days ago as seen in your locality.

First, specify your desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

Or use your JVM‘s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Capture the current date as seen in that zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Go back eight days.

```
LocalDate eightDaysAgo = today.minusDays( 8 ) ;
```

If you meant to go back to the previous Monday, use a `TemporalAdjuster`.

```
LocalDate previousMonday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previous( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

Get the first moment of that day. Pass your time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = eightDaysAgo.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

The time-of-day *may* be 00:00:00, but not necessarily. Some days on some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00:00.

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: Very instructive answer. Didn't pay attention that there's an overloaded flavor of `now()` expecting zone id.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Indeed there is. I recommend always using that method, **always passing a `ZoneId`**. Do so even when you want the default; pass  `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. I believe that with date-time work it's generally better to be explicit to make your intentions quite clear. Ditto with always passing a `Locale`, even if `Locale.getDefault()`.  So many programmers are either ignorant or forgetful of time zone & locale issues that using implicit defaults raises ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a LocalDateTime, which is a LocalDate with a time component (including timezone).

LocalDate does as it says on the tin, it gives you a date, not a date and time.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` does **not** include timezone - very first line of its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html): "A date-time without a time-zone ..."

Answer (score 0):

```java
LocalDateTime
 .of(LocalDate.now().with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)
 .minusWeeks(1)
```

Gives you start of last week at midnight (local time).

Comment: This code ignores the crucial issue of time zones. The result could be incorrect in some localities.

Answer (score -1):

```
@DateTimeFormat("HH:MM:SS")
@JsonFormat("HH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: This looks like Spring annotations, but since you give zero context for your answer I couldn't say for sure. OP does not mention using Spring in the question. This also does not address the problem that there is no time because OP is using LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime.